# regular expression js to python

Tags: javascript, python, regex, firefox-addon

I opened the Mozilla Firefox add-on [Wappalizer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/wappalyzer/) and saw the following JavaScript. Is this a regular expression, and is it possible to use it in python?

```
    'CO2Stats':              { cats: { 1: 10 }, html: /src=("|')http:\/\/www\.co2stats\.com\/propres\.php/ },
    'CodeIgniter':           { cats: { 1: 18 }, headers: { 'Set-Cookie': /(exp_last_activity|exp_tracker|ci_session)/ }, implies: [ 'PHP' ] },
    'Commerce Server':       { cats: { 1:  6 }, headers: { 'COMMERCE-SERVER-SOFTWARE': /.+/ } },
    'comScore':              { cats: { 1: 10 }, html: /<i{1}frame[^>]* (id=("|')comscore("|')|scr=[^>]+comscore)/, env: /^_?COMSCORE$/i },
    'Concrete5':             { cats: { 1:  1 }, meta: { 'generator': /concrete5/i } },
```

Comment: sure, it's a js regular expression, it could be possible to translate it in python re

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the strings that are in `//` here are regular expression and you can use them in python with help of the `re` module.

```
import re
if re.match('(exp_last_activity|exp_tracker|ci_session)', header_string):
  # do something
```

But you need to find what string you must analyze with this expressions, of course.